# Perforce: p4 set versus p4 info

Tags: perforce

I have recently started using perforce on Windows 7. I have the perforce synced on my local machine using P4V. I was trying to run some other tool that uses the path where my perforce local directory is mapped on my machine. It appears that it is picking up the wrong one. While trying to debug, I noticed that the 'p4 info' command returns the 'Client root' which is set to the wrong value. The 'p4 set' shows the P4ROOT which is the correct value.  What exactly is the difference between 'p4 set' and 'p4 info'? Can I update the 'Client root'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P4ROOT is a server-side setting and is (confusingly) not related to your client root.  The client root is set in the client spec that is specified via P4CLIENT and edited via the "p4 client" command.

To find the right value for P4CLIENT, look for the "Workspace" name in P4V ("workspace" is a synonym for "client").  Then tell the command line to use the same value like this:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=(client name)
```

Once you do this, you should already have the right client root, but if you needed to update the client root, you'd do it by running:

```
p4 client
```